# Searching a tree and outputting the path to that node in C++

Tags: c++, search, path, tree

Say we have the following structure:

```
struct ATree {
  string id;
  int numof_children;
  ATree *children[5];
};
```

How would I be able to search for an id and output the path to that id? I have a way of finding if the id is in the tree, but outputting the proper path is another story. I have tried using a string stream, but it doesn't seem to work properly (i get paths that include ids not leading to the id I want). NOTE: assume ids may only appear once in the tree

Should this be done using recursion? Or can it be done using loops?

Comment: Any recursion can be rewritten with loops.

Comment: I suggest storing the visited nodes in a `std::vector` or `std::list`, that's the path you've taken down to your node.

Comment: @littleadv: That's a stronger claim than I've heard before, and I don't think its true without implementing a stack elsewhere.

Comment: @MooingDuck - Computation 101, any recursive solution can be rewritten as iterative. That follows from the equivalence to the basic Turing machine. You'll need some more variables of course.

Comment: @littleadv: Correct, but in many cases the iteration must create a stack.  In which cases (if stackoverflow isn't a concern) it's usually simpler to go with recursion.

Comment: Stackoverflow definitely is of concern on this website :^)

Comment: @littleadv: An example of such is: a breadth first search cannot be written as iterative without the creation of some sort of stack.

Comment: @MooingDuck - BFS can certainly be created as iterative. The point is that there's no recursion, when you refer to the "stack datastructure" - it's just an array.

Answer (score 1):

I Belive that the following code give you a notion of what you should do (recursion):

```
bool find(const string& i_id, const ATree* i_tree, string& o_path) {
  if(!i_tree) return false;
  if (i_id == i_tree->id) {
    o_path = i_tree->id;
    return true;
  }
  string path;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < i_tree->numof_children; ++i) {
    if (find(id, i_tree->children[i], path)) {
      o_path = i_tree->id + '/' + path;
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Hi, why does the code return false in the if (i_id == i_tree->id), or is that a mistake? Also this might sound stupid, but where do I output the path (to stdout)? The location where I think it should go doesn't work if say the id is on the third level of the tree...

Comment: Nvm, I got it working using your idea+stringstream. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should basically keep the node from which you arrived to the current, for each node you're going through. Then just pop them out and print them when you found the correct path.

If you keep them in a `std::stack` structure it will be easy for you to just pop them when you're going back after reaching leaves and not finding the needed `id`.

If you do it recursively then you just have the stack of your calls and it should be enough, if you convert them to loops (iteratively), then you need the `std::stack` to remember the states, but it's fairly simple, really.

Comment: I cannot use a stack. An alternative?

Comment: @DillPixel - then maybe you should list all your limitations, instead of waiting for solutions and then saying that you're not allowed to use this or that?

Comment: Use my solution, it doesn't use a stack :)

Comment: @hochi, it does actually... It's recursive.

Comment: Ok, it doesn't use a `std::stack`. I thought that was clear since recursion usually uses the stack. Of course you can optimize out tail recursion etc. but refering to the general case.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this and also not very good... I did not even know a stack/vector type existed. Sorry for not mentioning earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Rough outline of algorithm:

```
std::vector< const ATree* >
getPath(const ATree* tree, const std::string& id)
{
        std::vector< const ATree* > path;

        if (tree->id == id) {
                path.push_back(tree);
        } else {
                for (int i=0; i < tree->numof_children; i++) {
                        std::vector< const ATree* > tmp=
                                getPath(tree->children[i], id);
                        if (tmp.size() > 0) {
                            path.push_back(tree);
                            path.insert(path.end(), tmp.begin(), tmp.end());
                                break;
                        }
                }
        }

        return path;
}
```

Comment: Now its better. The OP said he cannot use `std::stack`, I would guess the same would be for `std::vector`, but I think we can leave it to him to figure out how to change to what he's allowed to use.

Comment: I misread the requirements and it was meant as a rough outline. Now this code works, I've written a small tree creation and search example around it to verify.